# Need clarity on dimensional analysis

Tags: dimensional-analysis

I was reading about dimensions where in my book it said

> Note that in this type of calculation the magnitudes are not considered. It is equality of the type of quantity that enters. Thus, change in velocity, initial velocity, average velocity, final velocity all are equivalent in this discussion, each one is length/time.

I couldn't understand what they are trying to say from 'It is the equality....' to '.....each one is length/time.' I need some assistance.

Comment: Read https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_Introductory_Physics_-_Building_Models_to_Describe_Our_World_(Martin_Neary_Rinaldo_and_Woodman)/02%3A_Comparing_Model_and_Experiment/2.02%3A_Units_and_dimensions

Comment: What do they mean when they say 'type of quantity' ?

Comment: There are some basic types of quantities. A length quantity $L$, a time quantity $T$, a mass quantity $M$, and there is more, like temperature $\theta$, current $I$, moles $N$, and luminosity $J$.

Comment: I am really confused right now, here phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/…  ,they said that base quantities themselves are dimensions but in my book it said that 'when we write a physical quantity in terms of base quantity the exponent of the base quantity that enters the equation is the dimension' , can someone please clarify this ........

Comment: For example, dimensional analysis can't predict the $\frac12$ in the KE formula $\frac12mv^2$, but knows it's proportional to $mv^2$.

Comment: @DanielJoseph - no the dimension is not the exponent. The exponent is how many times the dimension is multiplied by. Like ${\rm [length]} = L^1$, ${\rm [area]} = L^2$, and ${\rm [volume]} = L^3$.

Comment: @John Alexiou- OK, But now i simply don't know what to do with my book

Comment: It says that _the type of quantity_ is what matters, not the amount.

Answer (score 1):

Let us see this simple calculation.
$$2 meter + 3 meter = 5 meter$$

When we do dimension analysis, we are not considered with value. So this statement would be analysed as
$$Length + Length = Length$$
or
$$[L] + [L] = [L]$$

Hope this example clears up the concept.

Comment: Usually, you put square braces around a quantity to designate its dimension. Like $[x] = L$ meaning the dimension of $x$ is length. There is an SI standard for this I think.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou: You are correct. I am editing my answer...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the escape velocity of a satellite in orbit at a distance $d$ from the center of a planet.   What could possibly contribute to the value?  It must depend on the mass of the planet $M$ and the strength of the gravitational force $G$.   We need to find a combination of those three variables that produces a velocity.  The only combination that I can think of is $$\sqrt{\frac{GM}{d}}$$

However, the actual value is $$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\frac{GM}{d}}$$

Dimensional analysis came close, but was off by a factor not too far from $1$. It turns out that the numerical prefactor is always of the order of 1.  So dimensional analysis gives the rough magnitude.

**Edit after comment about non-constant prefactors**

Perhaps a better way to approach my example is to rephrase the question:  What is the characteristic value of Xxxxxx (some quantity)?  Let's take the escape velocity of a satellite orbiting Earth.  How can we find the characteristic value of escape velocity?  The constants available to us are $G$, $M_e$ (mass of Earth)  $r_e$ (radius of Earth).   What we can call the  "characteristic escape velocity" is
$$v_e =\sqrt{\frac{GM_e}{r_e}}$$
We can add a non-constant prefactor by asking how this value changes with radius from the Earth.  To do this we create a dimensionless variable $\mu$ such that $d=\mu r_e$ so $\mu = d/r_e$.  We create a dimensionless function of the dimensionless variable $\mu$.  With that the characteristic escape velocity can be written $$\sqrt{\frac{1}{\mu}}\sqrt{\frac{GM}{r_e}}$$

---

The characteristic value for escape velocity near Earth is found by setting $\mu = 1$  All of this can be made more explicit by writing
$$\sqrt{\frac{r_e}{d}}\sqrt{\frac{GM}{r_e}}$$

This way of writing things makes it possible to create graphs that are uncluttered, and universal in the sense that the graph would be applicable to any planet.  For example, the full escape velocity at the characteristic radius is
$$v_e=\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r_e}}$$
Define a dimensionless velocity
$$\nu = \frac{v}{v_e}$$
and we can write
$$\frac{v}{v_e} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\mu}}$$
$$\nu = \sqrt{\frac{1}{\mu}}$$
Plot $\nu$ vs $\mu$ and you have a clean, elegant graph that applies to any planet and any radius from the center. This way of thinking and doing things follows from dimensional analysis.

Comment: Uh...I'm not sure how you come to the conclusion that the prefactor is always of order 1, unless you mean that in some kind of asymptotic sense (i.e. "a constant is automatically order 1 no matter how big it is"). I would argue that it is surprising that this is so often the case in real world scenarios, and that there is no generic feature of the math that causes it. Also that prefactor is generally nonconstant, because generically you have enough variables relative to dimensions that dimensionless quantities exist (which doesn't happen in your example but still).

Comment: If the prefactor is not constant, then it is a dimensionless function of dimensionless variables.  In that case you get the order of magnitude by taking the dimensionless variables equal to unity, and the value of the function will be O(1).   Perhaps there is no mathematical reason for things working this way, but I can't think of any examples where it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you are planning a trip to a suburb of another city.  You know that from your city to the other city is two hundred miles.  You ask your friend at your destination how far they are from the city center, and they say "about fifteen minutes."  So how long is your total trip?

Is it "two hundred miles plus fifteen minutes"?  That doesn't really make any sense.

In order to figure out the length of your trip, you have to choose one unit or the other.  When I take a highway trip, I tend to average about sixty miles per hour.  (I drive a little faster than that, but I also have to account for traffic, for bathroom and meal breaks, for sections at the beginning and the end that are on surface roads, et cetera.)  So for me, I'd expect the whole trip to take more than three hours (unless I really hurried, and also got lucky about traffic), but less than four hours.  If I really needed the mileage, I would need to make some assumption about my speed during those final fifteen minutes.

Now let's suppose that I want to paint my ceiling, and I'm trying to decide whether to build a scaffold or to buy a pair of painter's stilts.  The ceiling is nine feet high.  I'm six feet tall, so to do the work while standing comfortably, I probably want a two-foot lift.

Is there ever a circumstance where I would say something like "my height on the scaffold would be six feet plus nine seconds"?  There is not, because there is no velocity involved to relate those things.

If you ever find yourself doing some calculation and adding or subtracting numbers with different units (kilograms plus degrees Celsius), you have made an algebra mistake somewhere.

This also means that, if you have a problem with just a few parameters, you can often guess the solution without doing any physics at all.  A famous example is the Bohr model for the atom.  The Bohr model is quite flawed, but it correctly predicts the binding energy for hydrogen.  This success happens because the only free parameters in hydrogen (to good approximation) are the electron mass, the electron charge, and the quantum of angular momentum $\hbar$.  There's only one way to combine these to make an energy, and it happens to be the correct energy, instead of being off by a factor of two or $4\pi$ or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Read this nice article explaining it all:
[Introductory Physics - Building Models to Describe Our World (Martin et al.)](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book:_Introductory_Physics_-_Building_Models_to_Describe_Our_World_(Martin_Neary_Rinaldo_and_Woodman)/02:_Comparing_Model_and_Experiment/2.02:_Units_and_dimensions)

A quantity $x$ represents a numeric value and a unit. For example $100\; {\rm ft/hr}$. Each unit is a combination of basic "dimensions" and a scale (compared to the base units, usually the SI system)

| Unit | Scale | Dimension | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ${\rm m}$ | $1$ | $L$ | Length |
| ${\rm s}$ | $1$ | $T$ | Time |
| ${\rm kg}$ | $1$ | $M$ | Mass |
|  |  |  |  |
| ${\rm ft}$ | $0.3048$ | $L$ | Length |
| ${\rm hr}$ | $3600$ | $T$ | Time |
| ${\rm ft/hr}$ | $0.000084666\overline{6}$ | $L\, T^{-1}$ | Speed |

The scale allows us to convert the value of $100$ from one unit system to another. For example $100\,{\rm ft} = 100\, (0.3048) \,{\rm m} = 30.48\, {\rm m}$

But for **dimensional analysis**, the value is not important as we are not concerned with how much of something, but of what that something is. We analyze the dimension of quantities to understand how they fit together in mathematical expressions.

The notation usually used is to put square  brakets around a quantity in order to describe its dimensionality

$$ [ 100\, {\rm ft/hr}  ] = L\, T^{-1} $$

This tells us there is 100 of something that divide length with time. Its dimensionality is length/time. The value of 100 is ignored with the square brackets, as is the scaling of the unit. Only the dimensions in terms of how is length, mass and time combined to create this unit.

The rules for dimensional analysis is as follows:

1. **Addition** for $x+y=z$ to be valid, all quantities must have the same dimensionality $$[x] = [y] = [z]$$
   for example $$ [{\rm ft}] = [{\rm in}] = [{\rm m}] = L $$
2. **Subtraction** for $x-y=z$ to be valid, all quantities must have the same dimensionality $$[x] = [y] = [z]$$
   for example $$ [{\rm ft}] = [{\rm in}] = [{\rm m}] = L $$
3. **Multiplication** The expression $x\,y =z$ produces a result with the dimensionality of the arguments multiplied $$ [x\,y] = [x]\,[y] = [z] $$
   for example $$ [ (100 \,{\rm ft/hr})(60\,{\rm s})] = [{\rm ft/hr}]\,[{\rm s}] = L\, T^{-1}\; T = L $$
4. **Division** The expression $x / y =z$ produces a result with the dimensionality of the arguments divided $$ [x / y] = [x] / [y] = [z] $$
   for example $$ [ (100 \,{\rm ft})/(60\,{\rm min})] = [{\rm ft}]/[{\rm min}] = L / T = L\, T^{-1}$$